# How to include radio button in ember and how to get changed value ember-radio-button component

Tags: ember.js

I used https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button to include radio button,

```
{{radio-button value="green" groupValue=color changed="colorChanged" }}
```

I don't know how to get the changed value in `colorChanged` method in My component.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        colorChanged() {
            console.log('Color changed ');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking source  code,
https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button/blob/master/addon/components/radio-button.js

changedEvent function is triggering with changed value, so the answer is

```
actions: {
 colorChanged(newValue){
  console.log('Color changed Value'+newValue);
 }
}
```