# Ember js access value inside #each in the route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Trying to access the value of the radio button which is created inside a `#each` loop.

```
{{#each users as |user|}}
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
          {{radio-button value=user groupValue=owner classNames="radio"}}{{user.displayName}}
        </label>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

and in the route

```
console.log(get(controller, 'owner'));
```

But is always undefined. I've got no problem accessing the values of other radio buttons outside of the loop.

All questions around this seem to be from a couple of years ago and reference `views` which have since been depreciated.

Comment: in route ?? did you check by Ember.Inspector?

Comment: Check what exactly?

Comment: properties of controller. Can you provide demo? Link for page with app?

Comment: I'm not sure what further info you require, this seems like a pretty straight forward question. How do you access the value inside the ```#each``` loop on the route/controller?

Comment: You can't get radio-button compoent groupValue properties in controller directly. onclicking radio button it will change groupValue properties of radio-button component. to access it from controller, you need to set your controller properties in radio-button component changed function. For getting the changed value refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502763/in-ember-how-to-include-radio-button-and-how-to-get-changed-value-ember-radio-b?answertab=active#tab-top